# How to divide a m by n tensor to a m by 1 tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a 2 by 3 tensor such as:

```
t1 = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[8,9,10]])
```

And a 1D tensors of length 3:

```
t2 = tf.constant([.1,.2,0])
```

How can I divide all elements in the i-th row of `t1` by the i-th element in `t2` for all i=1,2,3. The results should be a 2 by 3 tensor:

```
[1/0.1  2/0.1  3/0.1

4/.2   5/0.2  6/0.2

8/0    9/0    10/0]
```

I don't want nans so anytime there is a division by 0 the results should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

First broadcast your second tensor, then divide `t1` by it:

```
t1 = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[8,9,10]], dtype=tf.float32)
t2 = tf.constant([.1,.2,0.001], dtype=tf.float32)

t2 = tf.transpose(tf.broadcast_to(t2,(t1.shape)))

print(t1/t3)

'''
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[   10.    ,    20.    ,    30.    ],
       [   20.    ,    25.    ,    30.    ],
       [ 7999.99  ,  9000.    , 10000.    ]], dtype=float32)>
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply dividing using `t1 / t2` will broadcast the shapes if your tensors don't have the same shape.

In this case, since you want *rowwise* division (divide each row of `t1` by `t2`), `t2` needs to have shape `(3,1)`, instead of `(3,)` in your example. So let's reshape it, then use the reshaped tensor for division.

```
>>> t3 = tf.reshape(t2, (3, 1))
>>> t1 / t3
array([[10., 20., 30.],
       [20., 25., 30.],
       [inf, inf, inf]], dtype=float32)>
```

Then, filter out the `inf` values.

```
>>> t4 = t1 / t3
>>> finite_vals = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.is_inf(t4))

# Cast to t1.dtype so you can multiply
>>> finite_vals_f = tf.cast(finite_vals, t1.dtype)

>>> tf.math.multiply_not_nan(t4, finite_vals_f)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[10., 20., 30.],
       [20., 25., 30.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. They are two different ways to solve the problem right? And ```t4``` I assume is ```t1``` in my description right?

Comment: @khemedi sorry, I forgot to add that `t4 = t1 / t3`

Comment: Thanks. I think it's also ```tf.math.multiply_no_nan```.  But your answer seems to be solving the issue, thank you!